# How do I parse Address into Street Number, Street Name, Type, Unit Number?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, functions, parse, address

How do I parse Address into Street Number, Name, Type, Unit Number? Is there a function which will conduct this?

```
2280 MEYERS AVE                                            
ALDERGROVE AVE & S VINEWOOD ST                             
SIMPSON WAY & N HALE AVE        
412 E WASHINGTON AVE #3                                                               
AVOCADO AVE & LEMON ST                                     
572 N TULIP ST                                             
1030 HAWAII PL                                             
500 N MIDWAY DR A-E, ADMIN
```

Comment: would adding a select + work for your process?

Comment: This might helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250683/sql-function-of-address-lines

Comment: Parsing an address is even more cumbersome than parsing a name.  You need a list of unit designations, directional abbreviations, logic for order, etc.  Is "10B Smith Street" the same as "10 Smith Street Apt B"?  (normally, yes)  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11160192/how-to-parse-freeform-street-postal-address-out-of-text-and-into-components for a very lengthy breakdown.

Comment: And hope that your only dealing with one set of legal bodies. Because if your dealing with international or unique standards it can be very lengthy. Hint: it’s partly why many online forms require the Country first before the other details are entered.